# Parcelable Map proper way?

Tags: android, parcelable

I m using a `Map` of String and `Pojo`. I m `implementing Parcelable` in that `class`. To generate `parcelable` I m using plugin `Android Parcelable code generator` by **Michal Charmas**. It's working fine for everything else, but not for `Map<String, Object>`. Here is my code

```
 @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeInt(this.driverDocuments.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Document> entry : this.driverDocuments.entrySet()) {
            dest.writeString(entry.getKey());
            dest.writeSerializable(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Off course if the map is null, it will throw null pointer. But if we apply the null check, it will miss the map when it's `null`. So I'm thinking of the proper recommended way to parcel Map. Anyone suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, In case anyone else needs help
Here is the working code, where my `Map` is of `Map<String,Document>` where Document is another `Pojo`.

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeByte((byte) (driverDocuments == null ? 0x00 : 0x01));
    if (driverDocuments != null) {
        dest.writeInt(this.driverDocuments.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Document> entry : this.driverDocuments.entrySet()) {
            dest.writeString(entry.getKey());
            dest.writeSerializable(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
 protected Model(Parcel in) {

    if (in.readByte() == 0X01) {
        int documentSize = in.readInt();
        this.driverDocuments = new HashMap<String, Document>(documentSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < documentSize; i++) {
            String key = in.readString();
            Document value = (Document) in.readSerializable();
            this.driverDocuments.put(key, value);
        }
    } else
        driverDocuments = null;
}
```